# how to select the drop down box in selenium web driver

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

```
Select se = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='33629']/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/select")));
se.selectByIndex(7);
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='33629']/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/select/option[8]")).click();
```

Above code doesn't work,please help

Error returned:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchWindowException: no such window: target window already closed from unknown error: web view not found
```

Comment: Above code does not work ? please anybody help ..

Comment: Please include the error that is occurring as the result of this, as well as the desired behaviour.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchWindowException: no such window: target window already closed
from unknown error: web view not found

Comment: Do you have `driver.close()` or `driver.quit()` before this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchWindowException: no such window

Means the browser is close when you are trying to interact with it. Remove `driver.close()` from your code and put it only after you have finished all you interactions with the browser.

> Edit

If you need to return to parent window after closing child window use `driver.switchTo()` again

```
// get parent window ID
String parentHandle = driver.getWindowHandle();

// switch to the new window
for (String handle : driver.getWindowHandles()) {
    if (!handle.equals(parentHandle))
    {
        driver.switchTo().window(handle);
    }
}

//do something with the new window

// switch back to the old window
driver.close();
driver.switchTo().window(parentHandle);
```

Comment: Sorry boss That driver.close only for child window only why click the parent window ?

Comment: Why does not click parent window ?

Answer (score -1):

```
windowIdbefore = driver.getWindowHandle();
System.out.println(windowIdbefore);
Set<String> windowid = driver.getWindowHandles();
for (String string : windowid) {
    System.out.println(string);
    driver.switchTo().window(string);
    // enter code here
}
WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
Select s=new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpathExpression")));
s.selectByVisibleText("text");
s.selectByValue("value");
s.selectByIndex(1);
```

Answer (score -2):

as i see here the dropdown box is present in div tag. i think with your code dropdown has been located but you are not able to select the value present in dropdown. Then follow below code

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(d, 10);
Actions builder = new Actions(d);

WebElement selectvalue = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("your drop down xpath value")));
builder.mouse.mouseMove(((Locatable)selectvalue).coordinates);      
selectvalue.click();

WebElement option = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("locator value of dropdown value(your dropdown value)")));
builder.mouse.mouseMove(((Locatable)option).coordinates);   
option.click();
System.out.println("dropdown value slected...");
```

Comment: The drop down is in `select` tag not `div`. There is no reason to do all this when there is `Select` class to handle dropdowns. In addition, your answer has nothing to do with the exception the OP got.

Comment: driver.close();